# Using tqdm progress bar on a function call

Tags: python, python-3.x, progress-bar, tqdm

Is there a way to use tqdm on a function call because i am not understanding how to display a progress bar because i don't have any loops:
this is where the function call happens :

```
if length == 2:
     post().request(email,password)
```

everytime it makes a request, i want my progress bar to move, is there a way ?

Answer (score 0):

So post is a class. As much I understood your question, you may try these:

For a progressbar for each request:

```
class post():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def req(self):
        for _ in trange(1):
            print("req")


p = post()
p.req()
```

For single progressbar for n_req requests:

```
class post(tqdm.tqdm):
    def __init__(self, n_req = 1):
        tqdm.tqdm.__init__(self)
        self.total = n_req

    def req(self, i):
        print("req", i)
        self.update()

n_req = 5
with post(n_req) as p:
    for i in range(n_req):
        p.req(i)

#------------OR-----------------

n_req = 5
with post(n_req) as p:
    p.req(1); p.req(2); p.req(3); p.req(4); p.req(5)
```

(I'm not sure why it's not working without `with` format. Probably because python objects or callbacks don't work same as c++ objects.)